# how to set different tabs width in a pagerslidingtabstrip

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

Hii Am currenly using a pagerslidingtabstrip and viewpager to host 3 slidding fragments. Everything works fine now but one of the title is a little bit longer than others! so it can't fit in the allocated place. so am getting some letters of that title and 3 dots. So i would like to ask if there is a good way to fix this such that each tab will take width corresponding to its lenght.

Note that it is possible to have this feature if i implement pagerAdapter with a layout(Viewpager and PagerTitleStrip as documented here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

Comment: I have managed to fix my issue by reducing the value of  app:tabPaddingLeftRight to "10dip" which was before to "15dip"! now everything looks perfects!! the solution suggested by nDroidDev was cool but it leave a blank space, on my case i was having a blank space on the right side of the tabs sections

Answer (score 2):

Try add this `app1:pstsShouldExpand="false"` property in your xml where you have defined PagerSlidingTabStrip

for example

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@color/tab_bg"
        app1:pstsTextAllCaps="false"
        app1:pstsShouldExpand="false"
         />
```

Comment: am using app:pstsShouldExpand="true" to let my tabs to fill in the whole space(width of the Activity). If i do app1:pstsShouldExpand="false" this will make my tabs to leave a blank space on the right side, which i don't want!

Comment: Also check your width property.. it should be match_parent like this..`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 0):

```
I'm try this and it's work for me

 1. Create new pagerTitleStrip layout, "my_tabs.xml"

   <code>< com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@id/materialviewpager_pagerTitleStrip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:pstsPaddingMiddle="true"
    app:pstsDividerPadding="20dp"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFF"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="2dp"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="false"
    app:pstsTabPaddingLeftRight="10dp"
    app:pstsTabTextAllCaps="true"
    tools:background="#A333"
    /> </code>

 2. On layout xml contain < com.github.florent37.materialviewpager.MaterialViewPager > set that new tab layout to your viewPager layout with : 
<code>app:viewpager_pagerTitleStrip="@layout/my_tabs"</code>

3. If still no working, add <code>.setShouldExpand(true);</code> on pagerActivity.java before setViewPager. 

<code>MaterialViewPager mViewPager;
    ....
mViewPager.getViewPager().setOffscreenPageLimit(mViewPager.getViewPager().getAdapter().getCount());
mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setShouldExpand(true); //Works
mViewPager.getPagerTitleStrip().setViewPager(mViewPager.getViewPager()); 
.... </code>
```